# adding time using javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, date

I want to adding a time with current time using javascript....

Easiest to set an example...
e.g.

In the admin section set the "Minimum Hours Booking Notice" as 12 hours ($minHours = 12)
The time now is 10:30 on 26th July 2011
I want to book a vehicle for today at 17:00

BUT 10:30 + $minHours < 17:00
THEREFORE I CANNOT make the booking. Then  I should be notified by a popup/ notice onscreen and the booking should not be allowed.

PHP Code for this.....

```
    $hour1 = $this->input->post('time1');
    $sec1 = $this->input->post('sec1');
    $act = $hour1 . ':' . $sec1;
    $min_hr = $this->input->post('min_hr');
    $current_time = date("H:i");
    $new_date = date('d');
    $exe = explode(':', $current_time);

    $new_time = $exe['0'] + $min_hr;
    if ($new_time > 24) {
        $new_time = $new_time - 24;
        $new_date = date('d') + 1;
    } else {
        $new_time = $new_time;
        $new_date = date('d');
    }


    if($date1 > $new_date){
        if($hour1 > $new_time){
            redirect('mesage');

        }  elseif ($hour1 == $new_time) {
            if($sec1 <= $exe['1']){
                redirect('mesage');                     
            }
        }

    } elseif ($date1 == $new_date) {
        if($hour1 < $new_time){
            redirect('mesage');

        }  elseif ($hour1 == $new_time) {
            if($sec1 <= $exe['1']){
                redirect('mesage');

            }
        }
    }
```

Please help....

Comment: What is the actual question?  Please be more specific about what you want help or advice on.

Comment: You've said "JavaScript" in the title and tagged the question `javascript`, but you quote a block of PHP code.

Comment: I want to convert this php code to javascript

Comment: Yes? So, what's your current javascript look like, then? What isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a LOT of issues with your code. I am posting an answer for formatting and to understand the code

This is not needed

```
 } else {
    $new_time = $new_time;
    $new_date = date('d');
 }
```

what is date1?

Why do you have sec1 when you obviously mean minutes

Where will the parameters for the script come from?

Here is your php in JS

```
var hour1 = qs('time1'); // qs is some function that for example uses the query string
var min1 = qs('sec1'); // you do mean minutes, no?
var act = hour1 + ':' + min1;
var min_hr = qs('min_hr');
var new_date = new Date();
var hh = new_date.getHours(); 
var mm = new_date.getMinutes(); 
var ss = new_date.getSeconds(); 

var new_time = hh + parseInt(min_hr);
if (new_time > 24) {
  new_time = new_time - 24;
  new_date.setDate(new_date.getDate()+1);
}

if(date1.getTime() > new_date.getTime(){ // where did date1 come from?
  if(hour1 > new_time){
    alert("message")
  }  
  else if (hour1 == new_time &&  min1 <= mm){
    alert("message")                     
  }
} 
else if (date1.getTime() == new_date.getTime() {
  if(hour1 < new_time){
    alert('message');
  }  
  else if (hour1 == new_time && min1 <= mm){
    alert('mesage');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For javascript datetime manupilation I would recommend **[Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/)** library.

It allows a flexible datetime addition and subtraction, ie.:

```
// Get today's date
Date.today();

// Add 5 days to today
Date.today().add(5).days();

// Get Friday of this week
Date.friday();

// Get March of this year
Date.march();

// Is today Friday?
Date.today().is().friday();  // true|false

// What day is it?
Date.today().getDayName();
```